# Mono on OSX: Absolute URIs are not supported

Tags: macos, mono, docx

I am trying to run [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) with Mono under OSX. I'm using a recent build, version 3.2.1.
Building with xbuild is successful but the Hello World example fails at runtime.

Basically, the populate document function (extract below):

```
public static DocX Create(string filename) {
            switch (rel.RelationshipType)
            {
                case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes":
                    document.endnotesPart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/" + rel.TargetUri.OriginalString.Replace("/word/", ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(document.endnotesPart.GetStream()))
                        document.endnotes = XDocument.Load(tr);
                    break;

                case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes":
                    document.footnotesPart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/" + rel.TargetUri.OriginalString.Replace("/word/", ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(document.footnotesPart.GetStream()))
                        document.footnotes = XDocument.Load(tr);
                    break;

                case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles":
                    document.stylesPart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/" + rel.TargetUri.OriginalString.Replace("/word/", ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(document.stylesPart.GetStream()))
                        document.styles = XDocument.Load(tr);
                    break;

                case "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/stylesWithEffects":
                    document.stylesWithEffectsPart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/" + rel.TargetUri.OriginalString.Replace("/word/", ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(document.stylesWithEffectsPart.GetStream()))
                        document.stylesWithEffects = XDocument.Load(tr);
                    break;

                case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable":
                    document.fontTablePart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/" + rel.TargetUri.OriginalString.Replace("/word/", ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(document.fontTablePart.GetStream()))
                        document.fontTable = XDocument.Load(tr);
                    break;

                case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering":
                    document.numberingPart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/" + rel.TargetUri.OriginalString.Replace("/word/", ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(document.numberingPart.GetStream()))
                        document.numbering = XDocument.Load(tr);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

fails with:

```
Unhandled Exception:
  System.ArgumentException: partUri
  Parameter name: Absolute URIs are not supported
at System.IO.Packaging.Check.PartUri (System.Uri partUri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart (System.Uri partUri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Novacode.DocX.PopulateDocument (Novacode.DocX document, System.IO.Packaging.Package package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Novacode.DocX.PostLoad (System.IO.Packaging.Package& package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Novacode.DocX.Load (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Novacode.DocX.Create (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

where Novacode is the namespace.

Being a beginner in CS/Mono, I don't get why the problem arises and why the output doesn't detail a more precise location (it's a debug build by default).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UriKind.Relative` instead of `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`.

Answer (score 0):

I have submited a patch applying a fix for this exception the patch number is 16266 by revobtz. This patch contains a fix that makes Docx portable to mono. Fix for the exception: absolute path not supported on mono os x, on creating a document. Tested on windows using VS and tested mac os x using xamarin.

**Update**

Download the latest version of DocX, the bug is already fixed.